# Why would turning on the A/C affect my alternator output voltage?

Tags: chevrolet, ac, alternator

So yet another chapter unfolds in the A/C gremlin saga of my LS1 Chevy.

#### Backdrop

- A/C compressor is relatively new (2 years old)
- One of the belts is squeaking (not sure which one)
- Recently performed a thermostat swap (the only reason why I mention this is because the thermostat housing is mounted directly above the compressor and a bit of coolant did spill on the compressor)

#### Symptoms

- The alternator outputs ~14.5 V with the A/C off.
- With the A/C on, the alternator outputs 10-12 V, the battery symbol lights up, and a 'Check Alternator' warning shows up on my display. After some time the steering goes hard as well, indicating loss of power steering. Cooling is abysmal.

#### My Thoughts

The symptoms appear to suggest that the compressor is inducing a parasitic draw on the engine (seized bearing, perhaps?), which surprises me since this is a two-belt setup (one for the A/C, one main).

#### Questions

- Is it reasonable to expect that a seized compressor bearing would cause loss of tension in the main belt to the extent that alternator and power steering pump functionality is compromised?
- Could there be some non-mechanical issue that explains this behavior (such as electrics)?

Comment: Year, Make, Model?

Comment: How much does the engine RPM drop when the A/C comes on? Is the voltage drop with the fan blower on high, or just on the low side?

Comment: could maybe be a short circle somewhere in A/C system. Check the Amperage at turning on/off the A/C. It can not be, that the alternator is not strong enough.

Comment: @Larry, 2004 Chevrolet Lumina SS (aka Pontiac GTO)

Comment: @Paulster2 : I'll have to check the RPM drop, but the issue persists regardless of fan speed. Engaging the A/C switch is enough to cause the voltage to drop.

Comment: I'm not talking about fan speed. What I'm wondering is if the engine speed drops to say 400RPM and stays there, your alternator may not be keeping up and causing you all of these issues. You'd have just enough engine speed to keep it running, but not enough to keep the alt energized as it's supposed to be. Long shot, but it seems like it might cover all of your symptoms in one fell swoop.

Comment: @Paulster2 : the absolute minimum RPM that the engine ticks over at is set to 650 RPM. The ECU never allows the RPM to drop below this value.

Comment: Just asking ... It *would* provide the answer to all your issues. Also, don't think that just because the PCM is set to ~650 rpm it's going to *absolutely* keep it there. I've seen other GM vehicles not idle right for various reasons, and they were all set the same as your LS engine. Sometimes we cannot see the forest for the trees. If you have preconceived notions of what the issue might be, you may never figure out what the real problem is.

Comment: @Paulster2 : Quick update. I popped the hood, started the engine and turned the A/C on. Initially both belts spun, then funny squeaking noises could be heard from (I think) the crank pulley. After about half a minute both belts stopped spinning along with the crank pulley. That explains why I was getting 12V output, but I'm surprised that the crank pulley stopped dead in its tracks even though the engine was turning over.

Comment: That would indicate to me the crank pulley is spinning on the crank shaft or the rubber has let go on the dampener part. I would not drive this until you get it sorted ... If it's spinning on the crank, this is a major fix. And the reason you're getting 12v output, is you're probably not really getting 12v output, but rather your battery is showing 12v.

Comment: @Paulster2 : It looks like the rubber's given out since I can rotate the outer ring by hand without turning the inner part of the pulley.

Comment: @Paulster2 : affirmative on your observation that it is battery voltage, not alternator output (I normally use the OBC secret menu to access battery voltage readout to check the alternator output, hence the confusion on my end :/ )

Comment: This will also affect the balance at the front end of the engine. You need to get this replaced and not run the engine until you do so. You stand the chance of destroying the front main bearing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As highlighted in the question comments, the culprit was the vibration damper on the crank pulley that had failed, causing the pulley center and outer ring to have some limited slip relative to one another.

I'm happy to say that the following symptoms were resolved.

- With the A/C disengaged, the crank pulley was spinning at a limited speed. This was also causing issues slight engine overheating and reduced power-steering assistance that I did not believe were related at the time of posting the question. With the new crank pulley in, things are much better; no overheating, A/C runs as before and the steering is easier.
- Engaging the A/C provided additional load on the crank pulley that was enough to cause it the outer ring to stop rotating. This was what caused the 'Check Alternator' message to appear and battery voltage to drop.
- Belt squeal is vastly reduced, so I probably will still have to replace them.